# Некорректные цвета при чтении изображения через ImageIO.read();

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

Я пытаюсь отобразить jpeg-файл в программе. С файлом проблем нет, однако цвета страдают. Сам файл я отображаю через openGl.

Код загрузки файла:

```
    byte[] data = null;

    try {
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\img\\SAM_0265.JPG"));
        data = ((DataBufferByte) img.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
        System.out.println(img.getColorModel());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(window.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Код отображения изображения:

```
        glLoadIdentity();

        glBegin(GL_POINTS);
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < data.length;i+= 3)
        { 
            glColor3b(data[i], data[i + 1], data[i + 2]);
            glVertex2d(x, y);
            x++;
            if(x == 1696)
            {
                y++;
                x = 0;
            }
        }
        glEnd();
```

Происходящие с ним метаморфозы:
[image]

```
glColor3f();
```

Дал несколько другие результаты.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а если попробовать через `glColor3ub`?

Comment: @AlexChermenin, после этого и перемены мест цветов сработало! Спасибо!

Comment: @AlexChermenin, можешь ответ добавить

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В данном случае нужно использовать `glColor3ub` вместо `glColor3b`, потому что метод `glColor3b` должен принимать три значения, каждое из которых в промежутке от `-128` до `127`, в то время как здесь используются значения в промежутке от `0` до `255`, которые как раз подходят под метод `glColor3ub`.